# 301 Redirect not working. 300 error?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

not sure what the issue is here. Please help.

I want to 301

http://www.thamesaerialservices.co.uk/services/aerials/

to

http://www.thamesaerialservices.co.uk/aerial_services/aerials.php

This is my .htaccess set up:

Redirect 301 /services/aerials/ /aerial_services/aerials.php

(no other code on .htaccess, just the redirect lines)

But i'm getting this 300 error:

Multiple Choices

The document name you requested (/aerial_services/index.phpsky/) could not be found on this server. However, we found documents with names similar to the one you requested.
Available documents:

/aerial_services/index.php/ (common basename)

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Do you have any other redirects in your htaccess?

Comment: @Howlin I have more redirect in my htaccess. Here are a few others:
Redirect 301 /services/ /aerial_services/index.php
Redirect 301 /services/aerials/ /aerial_services/aerials.php

Redirect 301 /services/sky/ /aerial_services/sky.php